Notes on Lachlan's monster
This is a duplicate of a question asked on MO months ago reposted here in hopes of success:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461432/notes-on-lachlans-monster
I have been trying to look for a reference I have seen in a paper called "R. Soare, Notes on Lachlan’s Monster Theorem" without success. I was wondering if anyone had a digital copy of them at hand and would be kind to share them with me.
